# OpenJPA distinct on

Tags: java, postgresql, openjpa

In my DB schema I have conversations with several emails. I want to get the newest emails from a list of conversations. In PostgreSql the query:

```
select distinct on (conversation_id) * 
from email 
where conversation_id in (7085214, 7084964) 
order by conversation_id, processing_date desc
```

OpenJPA:

```
(List<Email>) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT
   distinct(email.conversation.id), email FROM Email email WHERE
      email.conversation.id in :id ORDER BY email.conversation.id,
      email.processingDate DESC").setParameter("id", conversationIds);
```

It gives back a map of the conversation ids and the whole list of emails in the conversations.

How could I make it right?

Thanks

Comment: Is there no other solution? The mapping of the email object is quite long

Comment: The (standard) `distinct` operator is **not** a function. Writing `distinct(foo),bar` is the same as `distinct foo,bar`. All DB obfuscation layers (aka "ORM") use only the most basic SQL features available. The only way to use a DBMS specific feature is native SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use native SQL.

The only other way to do what you want is to develop a patch to OpenJPA that "teaches" it how to use the PostgreSQL extension `DISTINCT ON` in its JPQL parser and query generator. Most ORMs accept such extensions via dialect hooks. Don't expect this to be a simple task, though - unless you're writing a *lot* of these queries, native SQL is almost certain to be much easier.

You can't just use `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON` like functions. They aren't; they're completely separate syntax. A JPQL engine would try to convert it into a true function call that'd fail at runtime - or in the case of `distinct on`, just fail to parse it in the first place.

BTW, `DISTINCT ON` is a bit like `GROUP BY` in some other vendor databases like MySQL, where you're allowed to specify columns in the `SELECT` that don't appear in the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate. So in MySQL people probably do this by just producing a technically invalid query that MySQL accepts anyway - it's quite likely that the OpenJPA JPQL handler won't notice the problem, so it'll pass it through fine. This trick won't work for `DISTINCT ON` and PostgreSQL is strictly standards compliant about `GROUP BY`, it won't let you produce a non-deterministic query with `GROUP BY`.